# Swift Imageview Circular

Tags: swift3, uiimageview

I am trying to get my profile picture to display as a circular view using swift 3. This is my code:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.profileImageView.image = image
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.width/2.0
self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
self.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

It works well on square images. But once the image is not square this doesn't display the image as circular. What do I need to do in order to get it to be display the imageview as a circle? Or is this feature only limited to square images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is making the corner radius half the width. This works fine when height == width (so radius also == height/2), but otherwise it won't work.

To fix this, add constraints to make your `profileImageView` square, then set the `profileImageView.contentMode = .aspectFill`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` line before you are set corner radius.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.width/2.0
self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Add  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() line before you are set corner radius.